# Temperature in Condo hotter than thermostat setting- Gas Furnace

Tags: furnace, thermostat

I recently bought my first place (a condo) and I have a gas furnace. The thermostat is set for 72 and most of the time it seems to be following this alright but periodically even though the thermostat is still set at 72 the furnace comes on and the temperature in the condo goes up to around 77-87. There isn't a day/time setting on the thermostat (though the thermostat is digital). Any advice as to why this might be happening?

Comment: I would remove the thermostat from the wall and make sure the hole in the wall where the wires come through are sealed so no cold  draft will come out the hole and affect the thermostat. Sometimes it is as easy putting some putty into this hole to stop the draft.The draft could be from a kitchen or bath exhaust vent pulling air out of the house. If this is not the cause " no harm no foul"

Answer (score -1):

I ended up having to call the furnace repairman. It turned out that the gas valve was stuck in the open position, leading to the overheating issue.